# Sending password with expect in shell script

Tags: shell, unix, expect

I have a small problem. I'm trying to scp to a remote server and have the script enter my password for me. In short, I'm trying to automate the password entry process in the prompt. However, every time I run my code I keep receiving the prompt to enter my password. Please help. Thank you.

```
#!bin/expect
for dest in $(<destinations.txt); do
    set pass "password"
    scp -r ${dest}:/home/car02fv/QATest.txt /home/car02fv/
    expect "car02fv@goxsd1703's password:"
    send pass
    interact
done
```

Comment: You're mixing shell and expect syntaxes: they are different languages that must be executed in different interpreters. Have a look through [other questions tagged expect and shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/expect+shell) for examples on how to do it right.

Comment: @glennjackman I see. This helps.